# How do I earn a higher level Sega License?

Tags: sonic-and-sega-all-stars-racing

On Sonic and Sega All Stars Racing on the PS3, there are various achievements for getting a higher level Sega License (it goes from green (original) to blue to amber to red to bronze to silver and finally to gold).

What are the requirements for each level of license?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you'll need to unlock the higher tier licenses is a *ton* of Sega Miles.  You'll get Sega Miles at the end of a race whether you win or lose, but winning gives you more.  The mile requirements are for total miles *earned*, so you can spend your miles without worrying about making the next license harder to get.

The license ranks are:

- Blue - 50,000 miles
- Amber - 100,000 miles
- Red - 150,000 miles
- Bronze - 300,000 miles
- Silver - 500,000 miles
- Gold - 750,000 miles

As getting these licenses are trophies/achievements, most of this info comes from the [PS3Trophies page](http://www.ps3trophies.org/game/sonic-sega-all-stars-racing/guide/) for this game.

Comment: Very cool! Good to know I can spend my miles without worrying I am screwing myself out of trophies. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Step One** : you need a rubber band

**Step Two** : put it around your remote

**Step Three** : make sure you put it on L1 not R2

**Step Four** : put on sonic alstars racing

**Step Five** : put it on time trial and make sure its casino park and it will go automatically after an hour you will earn near 25-30000 sega miles